# How to make uppercase only the odd indexes of a string in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make only the odd indexes of a string in uppercase (whereas the even indexes to be in lowercase) in MySQL.

For example: StackOverflow -> StAcKoVeRfLoW or hello -> HeLlO.

I found a way to this by extracting a letter at a time using the mid function, then concatenating based on which index the letter is at:

```
SET @x='hello';
SELECT @x as Initial,
Concat(ucase(mid(@x,1,1)),lcase(mid(@x,2,1)),ucase(mid(@x,3,1)),lcase(mid(@x,4,1)),ucase(mid(@x,5,1))) 
    as Final;
```

However I'm interested if there is a way to simplify this, since if the string would be larger then we would have some problems. So basically is there a way to modify it to something like:

```
Concat(ucase(mid(@x,odd index,1)),lcase(mid(@x,even index,1)))?
```

Comment: There's no such built-in function in MySQL. You need to write your own. I can imagine it will be slow if used in a query for large dataset.

Comment: This would be much easier to do in your application software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably most simply done in your application, but can be achieved in MySQL. For MySQL 8+ you can use a recursive CTE to extract the individual letters from the string and `GROUP_CONCAT` to put them back together, changing the case on an alternating basis:

```
WITH RECURSIVE INITIAL AS (
    SELECT 'StackOverflow' AS x
),
CTE AS (
    SELECT 1 AS upper, SUBSTRING(x, 1, 1) AS letter, SUBSTRING(x, 2) AS remainder 
    FROM INITIAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 - upper, SUBSTRING(remainder, 1, 1), SUBSTRING(remainder, 2)
    FROM CTE
    WHERE LENGTH(remainder) > 0
)
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN upper THEN UPPER(letter) ELSE LOWER(letter) END SEPARATOR '') AS new
FROM CTE
```

Output:

```
StAcKoVeRfLoW
```

In versions lower than 8, you can use a user-defined function:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION AlterCase(initial TEXT)
RETURNS TEXT 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE l CHAR(1);
  DECLARE new TEXT DEFAULT '';
  WHILE i <= LENGTH(initial) DO
    SET l = SUBSTRING(initial, i, 1);
    SET new = CONCAT(new,
                     CASE WHEN i % 2 = 1 THEN UPPER(l) ELSE LOWER(l) END);
    SET i = i + 1;
  END WHILE;
  RETURN new;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

And call it as

```
SELECT AlterCase('StackOverflow')
```

Output:

```
StAcKoVeRfLoW
```

Note the function will work in MySQL 8+ too.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7GortFbYDgVagG6WekykHy/1)

Comment: @Nyssa I have added a function solution which is easier to understand and can work in all versions of MySQL

Comment: Thank you, I understand what is going on with the function, however I'm not sure how to use the function (I'm using phpMyAdmin at this moment). Do you have any resources/tutorial to recommend me about how to use functions?

Comment: If you copy and paste the code into an SQL query in phpMyAdmin it will define the function for you. You can then run queries like `SELECT AlterCase('StackOverflow')`. In terms of resources for learning, I think [MySQLTutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/) has really clear explanations and a lot of people use [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp)

Comment: That's weird; maybe you missed the `DELIMITER //` the first time? Anyway, I'm really glad to hear it's working for you,

Comment: Yes, I missed it, or actually I didn't copy it, thinking it's not necessary, but I googled about it now. Delimiter and Deterministic where the strange terms for me.